# Amazon Managed Blockchain not showing Ethereum network

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am a beginner in smart contract development. I just create a smart contract for some analyze how it works, so I used the truffle suite with vs code to create a smart contract. I create a sample smart contract and build it successfully without errors.

Now I trying to publish this smart contract in AWS. I have an AWS account (region - eu-west-2, Europe-London) and I already found the documentation about the Etherum network supported by the AWS [link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/announcing-general-availability-of-ethereum-on-amazon-managed-blockchain/). And this documentation already mentioned the available regions too.

But when I try to create a new private network it only shows 'Hyperledger fabric network'.

[image]

In the documentation, it shows the 'Ethereum' network like the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am glad to help you here. I am Everton Fraga, working for AWS as Sr. Blockchain Specialist.

On the Managed Blockchain service page, https://console.aws.amazon.com/managedblockchain/, click on "Join public network", then you will be guided to deploy your Ethereum node on the network of choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply, I am still trying to create a blockchain network in my AWS Port (on behalf of my employer ). Now I changed the network to Hyperledger Fabric, and trying to create a blockchain on followin tutorial.

Comment: Please refer to the tutorial link - https://track-and-trace-blockchain.workshop.aws/ 
Now I am stuck on the ( Set up a Fabric client > Configure client instance > Enroll Fabric admin  ) because in this section They are trying to download the '.pem' file from the S3 bucket, but this tutorial was doesn't mention the S3 Bucket in the perquisites, then how this works? I mean how was this '.pem' file created in the s3 bucket?